# discord.py-rewrite 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'ws'

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is code:

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def join(ctx):
        global voice1
        global channel1
        channel1 = ctx.author.voice.channel
        voice1 = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice1 and voice1.is_connected():
            await voice1.move_to(channel1)
        else:
            await channel1.connect()
            await ctx.send(f"joined {channel1}")
```

I got this error:

```
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 
    'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'ws'
```

I try make a music bot

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? Let `voice_client` is an instance of `VoiceClient` class. Your error means that you write `voice_client.ws()`... There's nothing like this in the code you provided. Can you please post the **full traceback**, may be there can be a clue?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(name='join', invoke_without_subcommand=True)
async def join(ctx):
   destination = ctx.author.voice.channel
   if ctx.voice_state.voice:
     await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination)
     return

   ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()
   await ctx.send(f"Joined {ctx.author.voice.channel} Voice Channel")
```

try using this
i think it should be because recently discord changed its documentations and introduced some new features.